# Is it possible to control the HTTP response behavior in openCPU?

Tags: r, http, opencpu

According to [the openCPU documentation](https://www.opencpu.org/api.html#api-status), there are some default HTTP status codes and return types for a few situations. For example, when R raises an error, openCPU returns code `400` with a response type of `text/plain`.

While I believe it should be possible to control those things, is it possible to customize any of those things directly from R? For example, what if I wanted to return a JSON for a specific error in my R function, with a status code 503?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change their R package behavior by forking opencpu or via a local copy i.e. not sure if package allows this like a functionality but the responses are configured in [res.R](https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu/blob/692cccf8d692990e3fc92b78f7cd668b69daf0c0/R/res.R)

For e.g. this method in the link above uses `400` for error.

```
error <- function(msg, status=400){
    setbody(msg);
    finish(status);
  }
```

I will update the answer if I can confirm this is available without changing package code.

### UPDATE 17-04-2021

You can write your serving html i.e. index.html which uses `opencpu.js` to call the corresponding R functions from your app, the return type can be requested to be `json` in the `opencpu.js` call. And in the R function , you can `tryCatch()` errors to send appropriate error code as a json argument.

For e.g. in the [stock example app](https://github.com/rwebapps/stockapp) you can see the file [stock.js](https://github.com/rwebapps/stockapp/blob/master/inst/www/stocks.js) which calls the functions from `R` folder i.e.

```js
//this function gets a list of stocks to populate the tree panel
  function loadtree(){
    var req = ocpu.rpc("listbyindustry", {}, function(data){
      Ext.getCmp("tree-panel").getStore().setProxy({
        type : "memory",
        data : data,
        reader : {
          type: "json"
        }
      });
      Ext.getCmp("tree-panel").getStore().load();
    }).fail(function(){
      alert("Failed to load stocks: " + req.responseText);
    });
  }
```

The corresponding R code being called is in [listbyindustry.R](https://github.com/rwebapps/stockapp/blob/master/R/listbyindustry.R), inside which you can `tryCatch()` and send custom `json`.

Comment: Any updates on that? It should be possible to do it without changing source code.

Comment: Its a feature request on their repo , still open, see [here](https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu/issues/111) for more details.

Note that text/plain response type is only for errors generated by R.
So the best bet you have is to do try catch in R and based on the results send a json object to the HTTP GET request , this way you can parse custom error codes (not really error codes but json messages/data).